# fp-ts: How to combine multiple Option producers?

Tags: typescript, fp-ts

I am looking for an `fp-ts` function that has this behavior:

```
function compute1(arg: number): Option<number>;
function compute2(arg: number): Option<number>;
function compute3(arg: number): Option<number>;

function compute(arg: number): Option<number> {
  const first = compute1(arg)
  if (isSome(first)) return first

  const second = compute2(arg)
  if (isSome(second)) return second

  const third = compute3(arg)
  if (isSome(third)) return third

  return none
}

// For example I am looking for this `or` function:
const compute = or([
  compute1,
  compute2,
  compute3,
])
```

I was not able to find a corresponding function [in the documentation of `Option` here](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Option.ts.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for `getLastMonoid` within the Option library. This will give you the right most `some` value as shown in the table below:

| x | y | concat(x, y) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| none | none | none |
| some(a) | none | some(a) |
| none | some(a) | some(a) |
| some(a) | some(b) | some(b) |

However, this only helps you for pairs of `Option`, in order to apply it to an array of `Option`, you will need to rely on the `reduceRight` function inside [Array](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Array.ts.html#reduceright). Similar to the reduce function inside vanilla javascript arrays, it will take an initial value B and pass it through a function `f`until it has gone through the entire array.

Putting all this together, your compute function can be replaced with the below:

```
import { getLastMonoid, some, none, Option } from "fp-ts/lib/Option";
import { reduceRight } from "fp-ts/lib/Array";

import { pipe } from "fp-ts/lib/function";

const M = getLastMonoid<number>();

const list = [some(1), some(2), some(3)];

const compute = (list: Option<number>[]): Option<number> =>
  pipe(list, reduceRight(none, M.concat));

console.log(compute(list)); // some(3)
```